# Are processes "sandboxed" by hardware?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, kernel, cpu

Can a process access all of the RAM or does the CPU give the process a specific part which the kernel decides, and the process (running in user space) can't change? In other words - is a process sandboxed by hardware, or can it do anything, but is monitored by the OS?

EDIT

I'm told in the comments that this is too broad, so let's assume x86/x64. I'll also add that the question arose while reading what I understood to say that processes can access all RAM - which seems to conflict with what I've read about security in OSs.

Comment: It depends on the o/s (and the h/w that the o/s is running on), but modern operating systems restrict what a process can do and a process cannot access all memory because the o/s limits what it is allowed to use, in part because of the virtual memory management.  But that does assume you're working on a system with memory management, etc.  If you're working with 8-bit micros in embedded systems, the chances that any process can access any memory.  But it still depends on the h/w and the o/s.

Comment: In modern hardware capable of running modern OSes, there is hardware support for setting the boundaries of a process's sandbox.  Mostly in the form of virtual memory, and running user-space processes in unprivileged mode (where privileged instructions trap to the kernel).

Comment: @PeterCordes  Thanks. (by the way, I updated the question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you count MS-DOS as an "operating system", then processes can do anything (and aren't monitored).  Even Windows95 doesn't have real memory protection, and a buggy process can crash the machine by scribbling over the wrong memory.

If you only count modern OSes with privilege separation (Unix/Linux, Windows NT and derivates), then processes are sandboxed.

AFAIK, there aren't really systems where there's monitoring of any kind other than "fault if you try to do something".  The kernel sets the boundaries, and the user-space process gets a fault if it tries to go outside them.

If you're imagining that maybe the kernel looks at what an unprivileged process does, and adapts accordingly, then no, that's not what happens.

---

See

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection:  Usually achieved by giving each process its own virtual address space ([virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)).  This is hardware-supported: every address your code uses is translated to a physical address by a fast translation cache ([TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer)), which caches the translation tables set up by the OS (aka page tables).

  A process can't directly modify its own page tables:  it has to ask the kernel to map more physical memory into its address space (e.g. as part of malloc()).  So the kernel has a chance to verify that the request is ok *before* doing it.

  Also, a process can ask the kernel to copy data to/from files (or other things) into its memory space.  (write/read system calls).
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space: normal processes run in user-mode, which is a mode provided by the hardware where privileged instructions will trap to the kernel.

Comment: I get that your answer to the question (in the title) is basically `yes`. But I'm perplexed as to why you emphasize the OS rather than the CPU. You don't even mention the hardware until after the horizontal line in your answer. Did I miss something?

Comment: @ispiro: All of the sandboxing mechanisms are hardware-supported.  When I said "the kernel sets the boundaries", it does that by programming the hardware, e.g. setting up the page tables.  Everything a computer does is CPU instructions (well, not counting DMA by devices writing directly to memory).  The hardware just reads instructions from memory and executes them, according to what the manuals say should happen.  "The kernel does X" is just a high level way of describing the process.  e.g. see [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to x86 manuals and guides.

Comment: Thanks. So the process is limited by what the CPU+MMU lets it access. I just can't wrap my head around calling what the CPU does "kernel" since using direct execution - when a process is executing code (until the next interrupt) - it's just the process and the CPU. The kernel doesn't exist (except insofar as the process is running in user mode instead of kernel mode. But that doesn't mean that the kernel mode code has any power at that moment. It's dormant.) Anyway, I won't take any more of your time. The answer to my question seems clear now. Thanks again.

Comment: well... MS-DOS does stand for "Microsoft disk **operating system**"

Comment: @ispiro: Right, the kernel isn't running any instructions at the moment, but the limits of the hardware-supported sandbox that it set up are still in place (including everything it stored in memory, like the page tables for the process).  That's what I was trying to say, and how you should think about it.  **A CPU is just a state-machine that follows rules, and part of that state remains under kernel control even while running instructions from unprivileged processes.**